# Insect hole in concrete floor

Tags: concrete, flooring, house

2 months after it's clear top coat application, these holes appeared with something cotton on the surface. It's very hard to pull it out. And there's like a something black that comes out of the hole when pulled. What's the remedy for this case?[image: see photos below for reference]

Comment: You need a concrete-devouring *shamir* exterminator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon's_shamir